# Writing a function in jquery to scroll to a particular div on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm approaching this as a learning experience rather than a simple lets steal somebody elses function. i.e the Jquery.scrollTo plugin.

I took a look at [this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12) implementation and got a little lost. Mainly regarding the hash and slice.

But what that achieves from his demo is basically what I want to write.

But i'm not too sure where to begin? Any tips would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is to jump to a specific position on the page, you can scroll from the top how far the element is from the top.

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#divId').offset().top);
```

Edit: For animation,

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#divId').offset().top}, "slow");
```

Comment: Spot on. anyway to add easing/animate functionality to this?

Comment: The ScrollTo plugin will give you scrolling with timing and easing options, callbacks, etc.  http://ajaxian.com/archives/jquery-scrollto-plugin

Answer (score 1):

for example the following code makes the following div always centered animated with smooth effect , change the speed next to top and make sure that div is absolte positioned

I gave this code as you asked for animation

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

            var top = ($(window).height() - $('#popUPdiv').height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop();
            $('#popUPdiv').stop(true).animate({ top: top }, 350);

    });
```